# JQuery get link and add variable depending on nth number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list set up containing links. Before this list is another link, this is the html:

```
<div class="catItemBody">
    <div class="catItemImage">
        <a href="index.html">Link</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="sigProBetton">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="catItemBody">
    <div class="catItemImage">
        <a href="index2.html">Link</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="sigProBetton">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

There are multiple .catItemBody on the page, each containing a unique link.

I also have some jquery which takes the first link (.catItemImage a) and applies it to each of the links in the list. What I am trying to do is modify this link depending on the list items nth number. I have been experimenting with the first link item using the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.catItemBody').each(function(){
        var linkitem = $('.catItemImage a', this).attr('href');
        if ($('ul.sigProBetton li').is(':nth-child(1)')){
            $('ul.sigProBetton li a', this).attr('href' , linkitem+'?image=1'); 
        } else {
            $('ul.sigProBetton li a', this).attr('href' , linkitem);
        }
    });

});
```

Eventually I want to build on this so that the link in the first item has the URL variable of ?image=1, then the second will have ?image=2 etc... I need the 'count' to reset so that the list in the next .catItemBody will start again at ?image=1.

At the moment, each link has the variable ?image=1 which is not ideal. I have set up a jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Dyfe6/.

EDIT
All of your answers seem to work but the problem is that I have more than one `.catItemBody` on the page, an updated jsfiddle can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/Dyfe6/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use nth-child.

I didn't understand if you wanted to reset or not the image count, so here it is not resetted :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var count = 0;
    $('.catItemBody').each(function () {
        var linkitem = $(this).find('.catItemImage a').attr('href');
        $(this).find('ul.sigProBetton li').each(function () {
            count++;
            $(this).find('a').attr('href', linkitem + '?image=' + count);
        });

    });
});
```

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Dyfe6/11/

And here it is resetted :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.catItemBody').each(function () {
        var linkitem = $(this).find('.catItemImage a').attr('href');
        $(this).find('ul.sigProBetton li').each(function (index) {
            $(this).find('a').attr('href', linkitem + '?image=' + (index + 1));
        });

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dyfe6/12/

Comment: The problem is there is more than one .catItemBody on the page so your answer only takes the link from the last .catItemBody, plus, the image count follows on to the next list in the next .catItemBody rather than resetting. I have updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the jQuery's `index()` method. http://api.jquery.com/index/

Here's the update jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ArtBIT/Dyfe6/4/

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way, but I've done it like this:

```
    var pre = $('.catItemImage').children('a').attr('href');
    var links = $('.sigProBetton li a'),count=1;
    $(links).each(function() {
        $(this).attr('href',pre+'?image='+count);
        count += 1;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**updated**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {


   $('.catItemBody').each(function () {
      var linkitem = $('.catItemImage a', this).attr('href');
      var $this=$(this); 
      $this.find('ul.sigProBetton li').each(function (index) {
         $this.find('a').attr('href', linkitem + '?image=' + (index + 1));
      });

   });
 });
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/Dyfe6/13/)

Comment: The problem is there is more than one .catItemBody on the page so your answer only takes the link from the last .catItemBody, plus, the image count follows on to the next list in the next .catItemBody rather than resetting.

Comment: you shoould add this to your question

Answer (score 0):

use `:first-child` instead of `:nth-child(1)`